# Where is SSMS.exe on Windows 2016 Server after default installation?

Tags: windows, ssms

I installed MSSQL Management Studio. It is not found in the Windows start menu for some reason. All materials on its location suggests starting with Start menu lookup - which doesn't work for this Windows 2016 Server for some reason. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

In default installation location I found the EXE under: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18/Common7/IDE -> Ssms(.exe)

[image]